# Handle negative testcases in spark applications - Pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a spark application, which does an ETL job, read from Kafka topic (structured streaming) in to dataframe which reads in the message in the topic as a string. Used regex to then extract the column fields from the string, then apply some aggregations on the fields.

This works well if the message in Kafka topic is given in a certain format, but when certain fields are missing stores null. How do I make the program display the exact issue and not a huge error?

I'm also trying to include input validation for the other units of the script, like for aggregation function check if the required columns are present or not, check if the cells in the dataframe are of a specific format or not, etc?

What could be the best way to handle input validation here? Do I use `try and except`? Or `assertions` before the aggregation function is applied?